# Creating a range from an array

Tags: arrays, swift, matrix, upsurge

I'm using this library called [Upsurge](https://github.com/aleph7/Upsurge) to handle some Matrix related functions.

One of those functions is creating a sub matrix from a matrix. Using Upsurge, it is possible to create a sub matrix given a range like this.

```
matrix[3...4, 0...1]
```

I;m faced with a situation where I need to create a sub matrix given two arrays specifying the number of rows and columns.

Since I can directly pass the arrays, I tried converting them to ranges like below.

```
let rows: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
let columns: [Int] = []

let rowsRange = Range(uncheckedBounds: (rows.startIndex, rows.endIndex))
let columnsRange = Range(uncheckedBounds: (columns.startIndex, columns.endIndex))

let subMatrix = matrix[rowsRange, columnsRange]
// Cannot subscript a value of type 'Matrix<Double>' with an index of type '(Range<Int>, Range<Int>)'
```

But I'm getting the following error.

> Cannot subscript a value of type 'Matrix< Double >' with an index of type '(Range< Int >, Range< Int >)'

Is that the correct way to convert an array to a range? Or am I doing something else wrong here?

Comment: I am not familiar with Upsurge, but what are you trying to achieve? Your rowsRange depends only on the *indices* of the rows array, not on the array elements. What would be the expected result for `let rows = [1, 4, 7, 99]`? – Perhaps `let rowsRange = rows.first! ... rows.last!` is what you need?

Comment: @MartinR Yes! That's what I was looking for. Thanks! You can post it as an answer.

Comment: But your question is still unclear. Why do you use an array? With `rows = [1, 4, 7, 99]` that would give you a submatrix with all rows 1...99, is that really what you want?

Comment: @MartinR Okay, it's a bit of a long problem. I have this piece of [Java code](http://pastebin.com/SSb0AE6R). It uses Apache's RealMatrix library. It has a function called [`getSubmatrix`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/RealMatrix.html#getSubMatrix(int[],%20int[])) which given a number of rows and columns, it creates a sub matrix out of it. I'm trying to replicate that in Swift.